# How do I determine the score of my questions?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban, score

I have been banned from asking questions on a Stack Exchange site. I now want to edit the questions I have asked with a negative score. Where can I see my question score?

Comment: see the [votes](https://askubuntu.com/users/96389/hendr%C3%A9?tab=questions)

Comment: Banned on all Stack Exchange sites? Or just on a single site?

Comment: @PeterMortensen it's very unlikely someone will be question banned on all sites. This is not about suspension done by moderators or SE employees for bad behavior, but rather automatic ban put in place when the questions on specific site get too many downvotes.

Comment: @PeterMortensen only on one site. Stackoverflow.

Comment: I have 7 questions in total with only one question a down vote. I restructured the question for the down vote. Not sure how is going to go and up vote the question though. This is what my questions look like https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916013/hendr%C3%A9?tab=questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A negative score means the number of downvotes is higher than the number of upvotes. You see the vote count (score) next to your question. Or in [your questions profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=questions).

You can easily search for questions that have a negative score. Use this search query:

```
user:me is:q score:..-1
```

This will search for all negatively scored questions. You can put that in the search box on the site you want to view your questions.

By adding `deleted:1` you can see your deleted questions too (if you have at least 10K reputation):

```
user:me is:q score:..-1 deleted:1
```

If that doesn't work for you, click the `deleted recent questions` link under your question page.

Those questions need undeletion before the score can change, so you might need to custom flag them after you edited them.